# Error during installation Prestashop using Percona 5.7

Tags: percona

We are setting up a high availability environment with Prestashop version 8.1.3, however, when performing ht e installaction via CLI, an error is always presented when using Percona 5.7 as a cluster.

```
[console] Error thrown while running command "prestashop:schema:update-without-foreign --env=prod". Message: "There is no active transaction" ["exception" => PDOException { …},"command" => "prestashop:schema:update-without-foreign --env=prod","message" => "There is no active transaction"]
```

```
*ERROR*         v8.1.3  2024/02/19 - 14:50:36: In Connection.php line 1854:
*ERROR*         v8.1.3  2024/02/19 - 14:50:36:                                   
*ERROR*         v8.1.3  2024/02/19 - 14:50:36:   There is no active transaction  
*ERROR*         v8.1.3  2024/02/19 - 14:50:36:                                   
*ERROR*         v8.1.3  2024/02/19 - 14:50:36: 
*ERROR*         v8.1.3  2024/02/19 - 14:50:36: prestashop:schema:update-without-foreign [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--id_shop [ID_SHOP]] [--id_shop_group [ID_SHOP_GROUP]] [--] <command>
*ERROR*         v8.1.3  2024/02/19 - 14:50:36: 
*ERROR*         v8.1.3  2024/02/19 - 14:50:36:
```

Is Prestashop compatible with Percona in a cluster?

Thanks.